# Mongoid - Accessing models raising an error in test DB, but works in development DB (Model.first, Model.all.count, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I had some tests that had errors when trying to initialize a collection. And I noticed the same thing in the console.

The following code works fine in `rails console`, but it throws the following error in `rails console test`. It will not throw an error creating the `Mongoid::Criteria`, only when trying to access a record.

```
irb(main):001:0>  Activity.last
D, [2015-10-29T14:28:25.920178 #39467] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding localhost:27017 to the cluster.
KeyError: key not found: "primary"
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:68:in `fetch'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:68:in `get'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/client.rb:192:in `read_preference'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/collection.rb:104:in `read_preference'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:411:in `default_read'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:300:in `read'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:40:in `block in each'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:46:in `call'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:46:in `read_with_retry'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:39:in `each'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:207:in `each'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:338:in `first'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:338:in `block (2 levels) in last'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:576:in `with_inverse_sorting'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:337:in `block in last'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:489:in `try_cache'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:336:in `last'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `last'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.0/lib/mongoid/findable.rb:158:in `last'
  from (irb):1
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

I usually use Postgres, and whenever there's a issue in a test db but not development, `rake db:test:prepare` usually fixes the issue, but that didnt work here.

Any idea whats causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I found answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/osI2RqdKEDM

In my configuration the issue was in mongoid.yml's test DB config:

```
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: db_name
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

I just removed this:

```
read:
  mode: primary
```